# Conditions for the natural maps of stalks $(f_*\mathscr{F})_{f(x)} \to \mathscr{F}_x$ to be isomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, proof-verification

All that follows is very easy but I've got myself a bit confused learning about open and closed immersions in algebraic geometry and so I would be immensely grateful if someone would check the following very basic arguments! Many thanks :)

---

**Set-up:** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous map.

Suppose that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image and that either

a) $f(X)$ is closed in $Y,$ or

b) $f(X)$ is open in $Y.$

---

**Lemma:** Every open subset $U$ of $X$ is of the form $f^{-1}(V)$ for some open subset $V$ of $Y.$

---

*Proof:* a) Clearly $E=X\setminus U$ is closed in $X.$

As $f$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(X),$ we have that $f(E)$ is closed in $f(X).$

Since $f(X)$ is closed in $Y,$ it follows that $f(E)$ is closed in $Y$ and so $V=Y\setminus f(E)$ is open in $Y.$

By injectivity of $f,$ it is clear that $U=f^{-1}(V).$

b) As $f$ is a homeomorphism onto $f(X),$ we have that $V=f(U)$ is open in $f(X).$

Since $f(X)$ is open in $Y,$ it follows that $V$ is open in $Y.$

By injectivity of $f,$ it is clear that $U=f^{-1}(V).$

---

**Application:** Suppose now that $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf (of rings, say) on $X.$

It follows immediately from the Lemma that, for each $x \in X,$ the natural map

$$(f_*\mathscr{F})_{f(x)} \to \mathscr{F}_x$$

is an isomorphism.

Comment: Yes everything is correct.

Comment: Many thanks! :)